# Sending order from ESP32 to Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino

I am new here and this my question regarding my graduation project.
I want to control the Arduino board from ESP32.

For example, a temperature sensor will be connected to the ESP32, when ESP32 read a certain temperature then will send information to the Arduino board. The Arduino board - connected to relay to switch the fan - will understand that is hot and turn the relay.

Comment: This should be asked on SE.Arduino, not here. I have flagged it for migration. Do not cross-post. If it doesn't end up being migrated, then delete this post and ask on SE.Arduino - although if you do that, then the answer provided below will be lost.

Comment: sorry I am new to this website.
what is SE.Arduino?

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: Or, https://iot.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have asked, It looks quite straightforward to me so I am assuming that you are new to controllers. Apologies otherwise. What you need to do is:

1. Serially connect both devices (I2C/SPI).
2. Program ESP32 to send a command/message serially to Arduino to switch on/off the fan relay based on your temperature thresholds.
3. Program the Arduino to switch the fan relay on/off according to the received message.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
Yes, I am new to controllers.
I Did step 2 and 3. the only problem is with part 1, I searched for I2C connection and I did but there was a problem I do not know why. 
I did the setup like in this page https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/jeffpar0721/add-wifi-to-arduino-uno-663b9e?fbclid=IwAR0zr5xDVk2KzP3n3VmlaQPSZf4Lg1UDq2q7bGmWEgUafedlxachJ5wZsHw
instead of ESP8266 I just used my ESP32.

Comment: In the link you provided, I don't see anything about I2C connection. Please see this link: (https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-i2c-communication-works-and-how-to-use-it-with-arduino/) and this link: (https://robot-electronics.co.uk/i2c-tutorial). Note that it may look complicated but it is rather simple.

Comment: What you need to make I2C connection setup is: Two I2C devices(You have them already), two Jumper cables for Connection and maybe two pullup Resistors. (See if I2C pins on Arduino and/or ESp controller are internally puled up. If yes, you don't need pullup resistors). Rest is just a sequence of commands that you can easily write for both controllers.